# How to store sed result in variable in tcsh

Tags: sed, tcsh

In tcsh shell, I have :

```
set tF = downloadedTwitterWorkingFile.txt
set title = $(sed -n '/<title>/,/<\/title>/p' $tF)
```

which returns this error  :

```
Illegal variable name.
```

How do I put the result of the sed search into a variable?

The working solution is

`set tF=downloadedTwitterWorkingFile.txt`

`wget -O $tF -q https://twitter.com/i/streams/stream/686639666771046414`

`set title='sed -n '/<title>/,/<\/title>/p;/<\/title>/q' $tF`

`***with ticks not quotes around full sed statment***`

Comment: This is a worthwhile read: http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt ... along with http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Comment: Thank you for the advice unfortunately my instructor insists that all work be done in tcsh.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In BASH do:

```
title=$( sed -n '/<title>/,/<\/title>/p' $tF )
```

There should be a space after `$(` and before `)`

As TCSH doesn't support `$()` the equivalent would be the backticks(`).

```
title=`sed -n '/<title>/,/<\/title>/p' $tF`
```

Comment: Thank you, but still returns the same error. `$tF` is in fact a file name

Comment: Post the code where you assign `tF` please. You are supposed to assign it like `tf="mytextfile.txt"`

Comment: `set tF = downloadedTwitterWorkingFile.txt

wget -O $tF -q https://twitter.com/i/streams/stream/686639666771046414

set title = $( sed -n '/<title>/,/<\/title>/p;/<\/title>/q' $tF )
`

Comment: I tried removing the spaces where I initialized tF, didn't help. As a side note I tested that tF was assigned properly with echo and it was both with and without the spaces.

Comment: @505090 : Did you remove the spaces around `=` in title too?

Comment: @505090 : you are using single quotes instead of backticks in sed. The b backticks are usually seen just above the the Tab key on the keyboard. I mean the outer stuff of sed . Just copy and paste from below.

Comment: `'sed -n '/<title>/,/<\/title>/p;/<\/title>/q' $tF'` is wrong `\`sed -n '/<title>/,/<\/title>/p;/<\/title>/q' $tF\`` is correct

Comment: This answer is wrong on every point. This is `csh`, **not** a Bourne shell (and even in Bourne shell it's wrong).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker. Have you  followed the comments What is your valuable insight in saying it is wrong in a Bourne Shell?

Comment: `set` is not a valid Bourne shell command, the spaces around `$()` don't matter. None of that matters, though, since this is a **tcsh** question. Using a space after or before `=`  is fine, and it doesn't even have `$()`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker : By the way i was talking about bash not Bourne shell.  Moreover I was talking about spaces when you do something like `var=something` without using set. I am not sure if this is allowed in tcsh

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
set title = `sed -n '/<title>/,/<\/title>/p' $tF `
```

Comment: It seems to me, that $( command ) is a ksh/bash syntaxe.
For csh/tcsh you should use ` command `

Comment: replaced parentheses with ticks and now have a different error `Ambiguous input redirect`

Comment: @505090 - are you certain that error is being generated by this line? It seems to me you'd get that error if you were specifying too many inputs. In tcsh, try: `cat < foo < bar`. Alternately, is it possible that you forgot your single quotes, and the `<title` is being interpreted as input redirection?

Comment: Agree with @ghoti...
It seems like a problem with `<title` somewhere.

`> set tF=File.txt`
`> set title = \`sed -n '/<title>/,/<\/title>/p' $tF \` `
And then
`> echo $title `

works fine for me.
The output is empty just because there is nothing with "title" in my File.txt

Comment: @ghoti - Yes I am certain it is that line. Every line has been tested independently including the sed command in that line.

Comment: @505090 - From your comments on the other answer, it looks as if you failed to copy the quotes properly. Note that Paul's answer is correct, as it notes specifically what you *should* have done (and what would have worked had you gotten the quotes right).  The other answer is in fact *incorrect* since it advises to use `$( ... )` which is a bash-ism, and to remove spaces around your equals sign which is not a factor in tcsh.